# Discord.js - setStatus not being called inside .then

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm currently working on a Discord bot and I am querying the status of a server and trying to set the status of the bot to the status of the server (online=online, full=idle, offline=do not disturb).

I've tested a multitude of things. The `setStatus` methods *are* being called and I've tested that, but the status of the bot isn't updated. In addition, the `setActivity` method below does work every time. `res.status` and `res.playerCount` also display valid values. Also, setting the status to something like `dnd` in the top of the function before querying the server status works. Is it a problem with `.then`?

Please let me know if you need more information. I appreciate the help!

```
function updatePresence() {
    utils.getServerStatus(config.serverIp, config.serverPort)
        .then(res => {
            if(res.status == 'online') {
                client.user.setStatus('online');
            } else if(res.status == 'full') {
                client.user.setStatus('idle');
            } else {
                client.user.setStatus('dnd');
            }

            client.user.setActivity(res.status == 'offline' ? 'server OFFLINE' : `${res.playerCount} players online`, { type: 'WATCHING' });
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `.catch(console.error)` to see what it outputs. Try this since you only have to call catch once:

```js
function updatePresence() {
    utils.getServerStatus(config.serverIp, config.serverPort)
        .then(res => {
            const data = { online: "online", full: "idle" };
            return client.user.setPresence({
                activity: {
                    name: res.status == 'offline' ? 'server OFFLINE' : `${res.playerCount} players online`,
                    type: "WATCHING"
                },
                status: data[res.status] || "dnd"
            })
        }).catch(console.error);;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! There doesn't seem to be any errors though, and the status still isn't refreshing.

EDIT: For some reason it appears to work after further testing - perhaps setPresence is more effective of a solution than setStatus.

Comment: Np, I just realized the reason it didn't log any errors was because the catch was inside the then function, if there was an error it would go to the parent. `utils.getServerStatus(...).then().catch()` would be the correct code, might not matter now but good to know for future debugging

Answer (score -1):

It's JavaScript.

Don't use double equation `==` but triple one `===`, so your code should look like:

```js
function updatePresence() {
    utils.getServerStatus(config.serverIp, config.serverPort)
        .then(res => {
            if(res.status === 'online') {
                client.user.setStatus('online');
            } else if(res.status === 'full') {
                client.user.setStatus('idle');
            } else {
                client.user.setStatus('dnd');
            }

            client.user.setActivity(res.status === 'offline' ? 'server OFFLINE' : `${res.playerCount} players online`, { type: 'WATCHING' });
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, I tested your solution and it didn't seem to work. However, the other answer to this question was able to fix it through a different method.